# Вопрос про INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, inner-join

Есть запрос inner join:

```
SELECT u1.vk_id, u1.first_name, u1.last_name, logs.lfrom, logs.lto FROM logs INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = logs.lfrom INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = logs.lto WHERE logs.ltype = 2 AND logs.lmodule = 8 AND (logs.lfrom = 156650173 OR logs.lto = 156650173) ORDER BY logs.lid DESC LIMIT 10
```

Он отображает:

[image]

И если заменить `SELECT u1.vk_id, u1.first_name, u1.last_name, logs.lfrom, logs.lto` на `SELECT *`, то:

[image]

Как бы выводится ещё и другое имя, так как в запросе прописано `ON u1.vk_id = logs.lfrom и ON u2.vk_id = logs.lto`. Но без `SELECT *` какие-то глюки и выводится одно имя. С чем это связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в первый запрос столбец u2.last_name, например.
Тоже ссылку дам:-) [JOINS](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html)

Comment: @msi, Вы гений! Спасибо!

Comment: Нужно просто один раз разобраться, а не использовать метод тыка.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте внимательно про джоин чтобы понимать как это работает например здесь: http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html

А так же, думаю, стоит обратить внимание как вы это загоняете в массив. Возможно дело не в SQL а адаптере, который получает данные.